# How to find common numbers or an anomaly in a 2D array and cause it to trigger something else

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array (a matrix of 10x10) with values ranging from 0 to -5.

I want a method to be triggered when there is a sequence of a value found within the array.

For example, there is a sequence of two negative 2. I want it to trigger an event/method that will give a bonus score of 4. This should happen only when there are two -2's and not if there is just one -2.

I tried achieving something like that but I cant figure out how to tell the program to only trigger when 'n' number of a value is found within the matrix.

```java
public class Test {
    static int board[][] = new int[10][10];

    public static void Test() {
        int i, j;
        board[0][0] = -1;
        board[0][1] = -1;
        board[1][1] = -2;
        board[1][2] = -2;
        board[1][3] = -2;
        board[1][4] = -2;

        for (i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("");
            for (j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
                //board[i][j] = 0;
                System.out.print(board[i][j]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void scanBoard() {
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
                if (board[i][j] == -1) {
                    System.out.println("Hello");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test(); //prints out whole array
        scanBoard(); //scans for 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
public class Main {
    static final int size = 10;
    static int[][] matrix = new int[size][size];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("The first matrix.\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                if (i == 3 && j > 3) {
                    matrix[i][j] = -2; //-2
                } else {
                    matrix[i][j] = 1;
                }
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        scanBoard();

        System.out.println("\nThe second matrix.\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                if (i == 9 && j > 5) {
                    matrix[i][j] = 2; //changed it from -2 to 2
                } else {
                    matrix[i][j] = 1;
                }
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        scanBoard();
    }

    static void scanBoard() {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                if (matrix[i][j] == -2 && (j + 3 < size)) {
                    if (matrix[i][j + 1] == -2 && matrix[i][j + 2] == -2 && matrix[i][j + 3] == -2) {
                        System.out.println("\nThere you go, a special effect!".toUpperCase());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the result you wished to see according to your request. I hope this helps you. And I did some changes in your code so it will be easier to read (In my opinion lol).

```java
public class Main {
    static final int size = 10;
    static int[][] matrix = new int[size][size];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("The first matrix.\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                if (i == 9 && (j == 0 || j == 1)) {
                    matrix[i][j] = -2; //-2
                } else {
                    matrix[i][j] = 1;
                }
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        scanBoard();

        System.out.println("\nThe second matrix.\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                if (i == 8 && (j == 5 || j == 6)) {
                    matrix[i][j] = 2; //changed it from -2 to 2
                } else {
                    matrix[i][j] = 1;
                }
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        scanBoard();
    }

    static void scanBoard() {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                if (matrix[i][j] == -2 && (j + 1 < size)) {
                    if (matrix[i][j + 1] == -2) {
                        //You can remove the '.toUpperCase()', it's just my personal preference
                        System.out.println("\nThere you go, a special effect!".toUpperCase());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for this. it did work. but what if I wanted the special effect to appear only if -2 was found n times in the matrix. (currently it is -2 twice I believe. so what if I wanted -2 but four times to trigger the special effect) tyvm again :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from the problem statement and comments, you want your scanBoard to behave like this:

```java
public static void scanBoard(int value, int frequency) {
    int i, j;
    if (value <= 0 && value >= -5 && frequency >= 2 && frequency <= 10) {
        for (i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            int rowFrequency = 0;
            for (j = 1; j < board.length; j++) {
                if (board[i][j] == value && board[i][j - 1] == value) {
                    rowFrequency++;
                } else {
                    rowFrequency = 0;
                }
                if (rowFrequency + 1 >= frequency) {
                    System.out.println("Hello");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test(); //prints out whole array
    scanBoard(-2, 4); //prints Hello once
    scanBoard(-2, 3); //prints Hello twice
    scanBoard(-2, 3); //prints Hello thrice
}
```